# Could not calculate build plan at the creation of a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I just created a new maven project, at the creation, I already have an error :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom pom.xml /WD_Automation  line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)  pom.xml /WD_Automation  line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom    pom.xml /WD_Automation  line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile) pom.xml /WD_Automation  line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

I don't understand why because I haven't touch anything in the pom or anything else.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Proxy/Firewall issue...

Answer (score 2):

Maven tries to download plugins from MavenCentral, but fails. This is usually a network or proxy problem.

Comment: Is there a solution if I cannot change the network or proxy ?

Comment: You can put the proxy configuration into the settings.xml

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, maybe this repository `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` is unreached for you, you can search for a usable repositroy on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 SR2 with java8 patches with Eclipse Photon 4.8.0, and the problem has gone.